# Why did Cyrus hire/pay a killer in Scandal Season 1?

Tags: plot-explanation, scandal

I'm meanwhile at the end of season 2 of Scandal, however there is one thing I have never understood: in the first season, Cyrus meets the killer (the ex-colleague of Huck) of Amanda Tanner in his garden and the killer tells him that the remaining money is due soon and that he would have to leave now.

Why would Cyrus pay to get rid of Amanda? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amanda Tanner was a former White house intern who had an affair with President Grant (see her profile here: http://scandal.wikia.com/wiki/Amanda_Tanner) she claims that she Is carrying his child.  Unfortunately Gideon Wallace (His profile here: http://scandal.wikia.com/wiki/Gideon_Wallace) a reporter for the DC Sun begins looking into her relationship with President Grant and is kept at bay by Olivia Pope after she offers him a breaking story.  As Cyrus is willing to do anything to keep this a secret (as he helped orchestrate the rigging of the votes in Defiance – Episode entitled Molly, you in danger, girl) and also keep Grant in power he hires Charlie who Is a former CIA agent B613 Operative (Here is his profile: http://scandal.wikia.com/wiki/Charlie) to kill her and the with it the scandal.

> Olivia: How did we get like this? When did we stop being people?
>   Cyrus: Were we ever people? Or did serving at the pleasure of the President just help us to shed our pesky skins and unmask us as the monsters we really are?